# Should I use pragmas or preprocessor macros in SQLite3?

Tags: c++, performance, sqlite, c-preprocessor, pragma

Is there a performance difference in SQLite3 whether I use PRAGMAs or preprocessor macros?

In my case, I wonder whether there is any difference between `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` and `#define SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS=1` regarding behavior or performance.

I tend to use the pragma to be more flexible, but I wonder whether there is some performance loss.

Additional question: Is it correct that the pragma applies to the connected database. Can there be race conditions if multiple processes/threads access the same database and set a pragma? I assume that the pragma information is stored in the sqlite3 file on the hard disk.

Comment: I'd go with pragmas; set them when you create your schema, and other devs won't have to look at your build system to figure out why a pragma has a non-default value. It also lets you use the system's sqlite library if you so choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no speed difference between the PRAGMA and the default setting.

This setting applies not to the database but to a database connection, so multiple connections cannot affect each other.

Comment: This implies that one connection can enable WAL mode and the other PERSIST at the same time? How can this be? Also, I think that foreign keys are a property of a database. How can two databases treat foreign keys (or ignore them) on the same database? Is it my task to make sure that all connections to the same database have the same pragmas?

Comment: "This setting" is PRAGMA foreign_keys. Other PRAGMAs have different effects. You can put foreign key constraints in every database; the PRAGMA just enables actually checking them.

Comment: Right. So other settings can cause race conditions if two connections use a different PRAGMA, e.g. for the journal mode?

Comment: Changes to the database file are always done using transactions.